# Python: count until element in list is a tuple

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
MyList = [2,3,(1,2),5]
```

where the elements 0, 1 and 3 are integers while the element 2 is a tuple. I would like to create a counter which tells me how many elements there are in the list **before the tuple comes**.
In the example, I would like a counter which will take the value 2 (2 elements, 2 and 3, before the first tuple). I have tried the following:

```
counter = 0
while MyList[counter] is not tuple: 
    counter = counter + 1
```

but it doesn't work because when it assesses the statement "(1,2) is not tuple" rather than raising a False it keeps on taking the value True. Any idea of what the problem could be and how I can get it fixed? Thanks.

Comment: try `isinstance` or `type(MyList[counter]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and `break` out:

```
counter = 0
for elem in MyList:
    if isinstance(elem, tuple):
        break
    counter += 1
```

or, using `enumerate()`:

```
for counter, elem in enumerate(MyList):
    if isinstance(elem, tuple):
        break

# counter *could* be unbound if `MyList` is empty
```

or you could use [`itertools.takewhile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

counter = sum(1 for elem in takewhile(lambda e: not isinstance(e, tuple), MyList))
```

Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> MyList = [2,3,(1,2),5]
>>> sum(1 for elem in takewhile(lambda e: not isinstance(e, tuple), MyList))
2
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to determine the type of an object:

```
>>> counter = 0
>>> while not isinstance(MyList[counter], tuple):
...     counter += 1
...
>>> counter
2
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use a generator. It the simplest you can have.

```
next(index for index, elem in enumerate(MyList) if isinstance(elem, tuple))
```

Comment: I don't know...creating a new list for this?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: May be use Sum on the generator?

Comment: Well, that's Martijn's answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I guess you might like my new answer

Comment: Indeed. It's probably a bit too clever for its own good, and I would never use it in practice (I bet you wouldn't have any idea what this is supposed to do if you saw it half a year from now), but it's fun.

Comment: +1 for pythonic one-liner because the question is equivalent to 'the index of first tuple element in a list'. And this answer also hints a generic and simple ersatz for `takewhile` and `dropwhile` in `itertools`. The only thing I would suggest is to wrap this line in `try...except` for `StopIteration`

Answer (score 3):

```
for i, e in enumerate([2,3,(1,2),5]):
  if isinstance(e, tuple):
    break
print i
```

Actually, this is one more example for a `find()` use case.  Unfortunately, Python doesn't offer one out of the box.  With it it would be just:

```
return find(lambda e: isinstance(e, tuple), [2,3,(1,2),5])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cnt = 0
elem = MyList[cnt]
while isinstance(elem, int):
  cnt+= 1
  elem = MyList[cnt]
return cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (possibly simpler) way to do it is:

```
MyList = [2,3,(1,2),5]
counter=0
for i in MyList:
    if type(i) == tuple:
        break
    counter+=1
print(counter)
```